# unable to understand why im not getting the proper output

Tags: ocaml

I've written a code for streams of factorial.

```
type 'a lazee = 'a hidden ref
and 'a hidden = Value of 'a 
               | Thunk of (unit -> 'a)

let demand (l: 'a lazee) : 'a = 
  force l; 
  match !l with
  | Value v -> v
  | Thunk f -> raise (Failure "shouldn't happen like this")

let force (l: 'a lazee) : unit = match !l with
  | Value _ -> ()
  | Thunk f -> l := Value (f ())

let rec zip (f: 'a -> 'b -> 'c) (s1: 'a stream) (s2: 'b stream) : 'c stream =
      match s1, s2 with
      | Cons (h1, t1), Cons (h2, t2) ->
         Cons (f h1 h2, delay (fun () -> zip f (demand t1) (demand t2)))

let delay (unit_to_x: unit -> 'a) : 'a lazee = 
  ref (Thunk unit_to_x)

let nats = from 1

    let mul_p x y =
      let () = print_endline ("multiplying " ^ string_of_int x ^ " and " ^
                                string_of_int y ^ ".")
      in x * y

let rec factorials () =
  Cons (1, delay (fun () -> zip mul_p nats (factorials ())))

let facts = factorials ()
```

I want to get the output like this,

```
multiplying 1 and 1.
multiplying 2 and 1.
multiplying 3 and 2.
multiplying 4 and 6.
multiplying 5 and 24.
```

the above output generates when I execute the following command in file itself: let () =
assert (take 5 facts = [1; 1; 2; 6; 24])

but when I execute the file in OCaml, I get multiple multiplications like this,

```
multiplying 1 and 1.
multiplying 1 and 1.
multiplying 2 and 1.
multiplying 2 and 1.
multiplying 3 and 2.
multiplying 1 and 1.
multiplying 2 and 1.
multiplying 3 and 2.
multiplying 4 and 6.
multiplying 1 and 1.
multiplying 2 and 1.
multiplying 3 and 2.
multiplying 4 and 6.
multiplying 5 and 24.
```

can someone fix this for me, I've tried several trial and errors but couldn't figure it out. thanks!

Comment: It's not really possible to help unless you give a self-contained example. I can't reproduce your results because you don't give definitions for `delay`, `Cons`, `nats`, or `zip`.

Comment: okay, ill update my question @ Jeffrey

Comment: What is `Cons` and `Thunk` and the stream and lazee types? Doesn't appear to be from the Stream module in the standard library...

Comment: You still don't define `Cons` or `Thunk` or the type `lazee`. Ideally you should test the code you post here to make sure it compiles. At any rate, my first guess is that you need a "lazy" facility that replaces a function with its value at the first call. This is the same answer I gave a week or so ago for this same question.

Comment: the code compiles and i get a long output instead of the one i want to get. its a long code honestly and i feel somethings wrong with the let rec factorials() part

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your implementation of demand is correct, your problem is indeed your definition of `factorials`:

```ml
let rec factorials () =
  Cons (1, delay (fun () -> zip mul_p nats (factorials ())))
```

Here, the inner call to `factorials ()` recreate a new stream value with a fresh inner reference and thus lose all sharing with the external call. Consequently, it needs to recompute all previously computed value of factorials without any memoization.

Thus, we need to define `factorials` as a single recursive value

```ml
let rec factorials =
  Cons(1, ref (Thunk (fun () -> zip mul_p nats factorials)))
```

Note that the function `delay` cannot used directly because the recursive value analyzer needs to be convinced that the recursive value, `factorial`, is correctly used in its own body.

Comment: there's an error that says "this expression has type int stream but an expression was expected of type int" and the "nats" is underlined

Comment: I forgot the call to `zip`, this is fixed.

Comment: the output is still the same and not the one i wanted. :/  thanks though :)

Comment: Then you have the wrong implementation of `demand`, and you are not memoizing the result of the Thunk application.

Comment: i just re edited my code with the demand function i have, can u see whats wrong?

Comment: You have not shared the implementation of force.But this looks correct. The error is thus elsewhere. As stated multiple time before, your code snapshot should be compilable by itself. Otherwise, it is hard to guess where your errors are located. With the right definition of the helpers functions, the implementation in my answer produces the right result.

Comment: i have also added the force function. any idea whats wrong?

Comment: As stated again and again and again, your code snapshot should compile by itself. At this point, the most probable issue is that you are not using `demand` in `take`. But you are making this harder than it should be by not providing the erroneous code.